# IIS Always Running Mode and Idle Time-Out

Tags: iis, configuration

There's probably a pretty easy answer to it but I'm confused about the effect of "idle time-out" when we set the start mode to always running on IIS. Shouldn't the always running, prevent the effect of idle time-out? What's the difference between setting idle time-out to zero and always running mode when the application has already started?